# what is the difference between console.log and return in a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, return, console.log

I am learning so I was solving an exercise which requires a script to determine whether the input number is a prime number or not, I initially placed a console.log in the loop and when the number 6 is tested, it printed out that 6 is not a prime number twice then printed another string "6 is a prime number".

I do not understand why it would such output be given, and why was false/not a prime number printed out twice, why twice precisely? and then once printed true/prime number.

However, I tried to amend the function and replaced the console.log with a return and the function works perfectly well.

I know return breaks out of the function, but does it also break out of the loop?

Although the function works I was just left wondering why this has happened, I might sound silly but I'm still a beginner so I really would appreciate your help, here is my code. Thanks in advance

```
function prime(n){
    for (var i = 2; i<n; i++){
        if (n%i==0) {
            return n + " is a not a prime number"
        } else if (n%i !== 0 ){
            return n + " is a prime number"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I know return breaks out of the function, but does it also break out of the loop?"` - Well, is the loop *in the function*?  If you're standing in your house, and you exit the house through the door, have you also exited the *room*?  Yes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: thanks for your input David, I now understood it, but I just want to correct my post, actually when I coded console.log instead, it printed out 2 false/not prime and 2 true/prime numbers, do you have any idea why that happened? thanks

Comment: @MohamedHegazy: Do I have any idea why code you haven't shown is behaving in a certain way?  No, no I don't.  I can't actually see your screen from here.

Comment: I meant that when the SAME code I posted is just replace with console.log for each return  statement, so virtually yes you can see my screen

Comment: Btw your `prime()` function is totally broken, because you `return` (and so, exit the function) to soon. Call `prime(15)`, the loop will start with `i = 2`,  and `15%2 !== 0`, so your function will return that 15 is a prime number, simply because it didn't try `%3` or `%5`

Comment: You probably got confused because running code from the developer console in a browser typically displays the results automatically. It's as if the console is passing the result of your `prime(6)` call to `console.log`. So that code wasn't really executed twice, its result just got displayed twice.

Comment: @Cohars yea I tried to fix this by starting the loop at 3 and it works, and inputting two conditionals at the beginning for numbers 1 and 2, still not enough for an optimum solution but it works anyway

Comment: The problem is not from where does the loop starts, it's that only one number is being tested, as you immediately return something, start at 3, call `prime(16)` , and  `16%3 !== 0`, you return that 16 is prime, well, the question is not about prime number testing and you'll plenty about it on internet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're going for :

```
function prime(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n + " is a not a prime number";
    }
    for (var i = 2, max = n / 2 + 1; i < max; i++) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return n + " is a not a prime number";
        }
    }
    return n + " is a prime number";
}
```

#### Explanation :

- You know that N is a not a prime number as soon as `n % i === 0` is `true` for any `i`. So when you find an `i` for which `n % i === 0` is `true`, you can return "N is a not a prime number" immediately, leaving the loop (and the function).
- After the `for`-loop is finished, you return "N is a prime number". The very fact that you haven't `return`ed anything yet when the `for`-loop is finished, means that the `if`-statement inside was never executed. This means that `n % i === 0` was never `true`, and therefore N is a prime number.
- 0 and 1 are special cases, which is what the first `if`-statement is for. If a positive number is smaller than 2, you know it can not be prime.
- `n % i === 0` will never be `true` for any `i` between `n / 2 + 1` and `n`, which means you can cut down the number of iterations for your loop by about half by stopping it at `max = n / 2 + 1`.

See [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m62nqzes/1/) for a demo.

Answer (score 3):

[`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) just outputs a message to the console. That's it.

`return` will exit the currently executing function.

Example:

```
function printStuff() {
  console.log("I'll print out");
  console.log("So will I");
  return;
  console.log("I won't :(");
}
```

`return` is also used to, well, return a value from a function. You can then use that value in various places such as `console.log`.

Example:

```
function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
var four = add(2, 2);
console.log(four); // 4
console.log(add(four, 2)); // 6
```

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, return will stop the function and return a *final* result, whereas console.log will simple log it to the console, without stopping the function. So, when your function used return it stopped your function from running the loop completely.

Comment: thanks for your input. is return to functions the same as break to loops?

Comment: Yes, Mohamed, return is to functions as break is to loops.

Answer (score 1):

"return" sends a value back to caller of the function. e.g.

```
var a = function() { 
    return "word";

    console.trace("hellllooooo");
}()
```

a, now equals the string word.

Also, it stops execution of the current function so the console.trace command will never be called.

---

"console.log()" on the other hand, writes whatever is inside it's parenthesis to the console (included in the dev tools of most browsers).

So, `console.log("words phrases nouns")` will spit "words phrases and nouns" into the console.